# Duedate Popup needs to appear once I click on that Task

Tags: calendar, popup, activiti, bpmn, bpmn.io

I'm having the Bpmn with the user and server task with no duedates. when I click on the corresponding task, duedate calendar popup needs to appear. After I select the date only, it have to move to the next Task

I have used the `activiti:dueDate="${dateVariable}"` in the Bpmn. But I'm not getting any popup

```
    <serviceTask id="GenerateFirstPassDesignerReviewSetVariables" name="Generate First Pass Designer Review Set Variables" activiti:class="com.hcp.core.actionhandlers.HcpSetGlobalVariablesActionHandler" activiti:dueDate="${dateVariable}">
        <activiti:field name="variableNames" stringValue="DesignerReviewNextTask"/>
        <activiti:field name="values" stringValue="GenerateFirstPass"/>
    </serviceTask>
```

here is the js file of date variable:

```
Core.Action({
        id: 'dateVariable',
        icon: 'calendar',
        invoke: function (context) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                var oldDate,
                    valid = false,
                    task = Ember.get(context, 'task'),
                    tasks = Ember.get(context, 'tasks'),
                    data = [];
                if (tasks) {
                    // If all tasks here already have a common date, detect that and use it.
                    oldDate = tasks.reduce(function (cur, next) {
                        if (cur === null || Ember.get(cur, 'dtDue') === Ember.get(next, 'dtDue')) {
                            return next;
                        }
                        return null;
                    }, null);
                    if (oldDate !== null) {
                        oldDate = Ember.get(oldDate, 'dtDue');
                    }
                } else if (task) {
                    oldDate = Ember.get(task, 'dtDue');
                }
                oldDate = oldDate ? Date.fromString(oldDate) : new Date();
                var focusTracker;
                $.timepicker.dialog(oldDate.format('%Y-%m-%d'), null, {
                    modal: true,
                    showTime: false,
                    showTimepicker: false,
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    stepMinute: 1,
                    beforeShow: function (date, dp, tp) {
                        requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                            dp.dpDiv.find('.ui-state-active').focus();
                        }.bind(this));
                    },
                    onShow: function (dp) {
                        dp.dpDiv.find('.ui-state-active').focus();
                        dp.dpDiv.on('focusout', function (e) {
                           if (e.relatedTarget === null || !dp.dpDiv[0].contains(e.relatedTarget)) {
                               requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                                  $(e.target).focus();
                               });
                               e.preventDefault();
                               return false;
                           }
                        });
                    },
                    onSelect: function (date, dp) {
                        valid = true;
                        requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                            dp.dpDiv.find('.ui-state-active').focus();
                        }.bind(this));
                    },
                    onClose: function (date) {
                        if (valid) {
                            date = Date.parse(date);
                            if (oldDate !== date) {
                                Core.Action('Core:updateTask', context, { dtDue: date }).then(resolve, reject);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        isValid: "(isTask || areTasks) && isWorkflowAdmin && isOpenTask"
    });
```

I need the due date calendar popup when I click on the task menu.

Comment: Can you please also add the relevant HTML/Js Code related to the pop-up?